# Ext JS 4 - Vertical ButtonGroup DOM Exception

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, buttongroup

Getting an exception like this while trying to have **a single column vertical buttongroup**:

**Uncaught Error: INDEX_SIZE_ERR: DOM Exception 1 [ext-all-dev.js:88026]**

```
var btn1 = Ext.create('Ext.button.Button', {
    text: 'BTN 1',
    iconCls: 'icon-database-go-32'
});

var btn2 = Ext.create('Ext.button.Button', {
    text: 'BTN 2',
    iconCls: 'icon-data-table-32'
});

var actions = Ext.create('Ext.container.ButtonGroup', {
    columns: 1,
    defaults: {
        scale: 'large',
        iconAlign: 'top',
        rowspan: 3
    },
    title: 'Actions',
    items: [btn1, btn2]
});

this.dockedItems = [{
    xtype: 'toolbar',
    dock: 'left',
    items: [actions]    
}];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the rowspan kills it. Here is a tested example that works

```
var actions = Ext.create('Ext.container.ButtonGroup', {
    columns: 1,
    title: 'Actions',
    items: [
    {
        text: 'BTN 2',
        iconCls: 'icon-data-table-32',
        scale: 'large',
        iconAlign: 'top'
    }, {
        text: 'BTN 1',
        iconCls: 'icon-database-go-32',
        scale: 'large',
        iconAlign: 'top'
    }]
});
```

Here is the **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BZC44/)**

Comment: actually it didn't work too.. I just see normal 16x16 icons rendered vertical. I need big (32x32) icons..

Comment: @lonelywarriour Would you please check the fiddle I added to my answer. I don't have buttons but the space looks like 32x32 for me.

Comment: thanks a lot @sra for your care, it worked after adding `defaults : { rowspan : 1 }`